# Bayes' Net Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I have the following Bayes Net.

[image: Bayes Net]

And I need to calculate $P(R\mid W)$ and $P(S\mid W)$.

For, $P(S\mid W)$, is it $.1 \cdot .9$ because I multiply the probabilities of those two events that the sprinkler is on given that the grass is wet?

Then, for $P(R\mid W)$, do I calculate is as  $.2 \cdot .99$ because I'm calculating the result of the event occurring given the grass is wet? I'm sorry if these are a naive way to approach these, I'm just so confused about Bayes Net and any help to calculate $P(R\mid W)$ and $P(S\mid W)$ would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea is to express the required probability in terms of those that are provided, e.g. $P(S\mid C),\;P(R\mid C),\;P(W\mid S,R)$. Normally, $P(C)$ would also be provided. I'll assume $P(C) = 0.5$.

Firstly, from the [definition of conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Kolmogorov_definition),

$$P(R\mid W) = P(R,W) / P(W) \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (1)$$

We obtain the two terms on the RHS in turn by: summing over the relevent missing random variables (line 1), applying the [Chain Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_(probability)) (line 2), using the independence properties of the given network (line 3), then expanding the sum and plugging in the numerical values (line 4):

\begin{align}
P(W) &= \sum_{c,r,s\in\{T,F\}} P(W,C=c,R=r,S=s) \\
& \\
&= \sum_{c,r,s\in\{T,F\}} P(W\mid C=c,R=r,S=s) P(R=r,S=s\mid C=c) P(C=c) \\
& \\
&= \sum_{c,r,s\in\{T,F\}} P(W\mid R=r,S=s) P(R=r\mid C=c) P(S=s\mid C=c) P(C=c) \\
& \\
&= (0.99\times 0.8\times 0.1 \times 0.5) \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{with $(c=T,\; r=T,\; s=T)$} \\
&= + (0.9\times 0.8\times 0.9 \times 0.5) \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{with $(c=T,\; r=T,\; s=F)$} \\
&= + (0.9\times 0.2\times 0.1 \times 0.5) \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{with $(c=T,\; r=F,\; s=T)$} \\
&= + (0\times 0.2\times 0.9 \times 0.5) \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{with $(c=T,\; r=F,\; s=F)$} \\
&= + (0.99\times 0.2\times 0.5 \times 0.5) \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{with $(c=F,\; r=T,\; s=T)$} \\
&= + (0.9\times 0.2\times 0.5 \times 0.5) \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{with $(c=F,\; r=T,\; s=F)$} \\
&= + (0.9\times 0.8\times 0.5 \times 0.5) \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{with $(c=F,\; r=F,\; s=T)$} \\
&= + (0\times 0.8\times 0.5 \times 0.5) \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{with $(c=F,\; r=F,\; s=F)$} \\
& \\
&= 0.6471.
\end{align}

Similarly for the other term:

\begin{align}
P(R,W) &= \sum_{c,s\in\{T,F\}} P(W,R,C=c,S=s) \\
& \\
&= \sum_{c,s\in\{T,F\}} P(W\mid C=c,R,S=s) P(R,S=s\mid C=c) P(C=c) \\
& \\
&= \sum_{c,s\in\{T,F\}} P(W\mid R,S=s) P(R\mid C=c) P(S=s\mid C=c) P(C=c) \\
& \\
&= (0.99\times 0.8\times 0.1 \times 0.5) \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{with $(c=T,\; s=T)$} \\
&= + (0.9\times 0.8\times 0.9 \times 0.5) \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{with $(c=T,\; s=F)$} \\
&= + (0.99\times 0.2\times 0.5 \times 0.5) \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{with $(c=F,\; s=T)$} \\
&= + (0.9\times 0.2\times 0.5 \times 0.5) \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{with $(c=F,\; s=F)$} \\
& \\
&= 0.4581.
\end{align}

Substitute these two values back into $(1)$ to give:

$$P(R\mid W) = 0.4581 / 0.6471 = 0.7079.$$

$\\$

The same method can be used to find $P(S\mid W)$.